# Mac OS X upgrade to Mavericks stuck

Tags: macos, osx-lion, upgrade, osx-mavericks

I downloaded the latest Mac OS X from AppStore to upgrade my Mac OS X 10.7.5

When I run the installer, after restarting it gave me an error regarding my **Macintoch HD** and it says that the problems couldn't be repaired asking me to restart backup my data then relunch the installer.

The problem is when I restart it keeps comming back to the installer, no mather what I did, I tried to fix the HD problem using diskutility but it also failed.

Also I have a HD of **1T** Where I wanted to backup my data `(using command line, since I can run the terminal)` but my external HD is *NTFS* therefore its read only

What I would like to do is:

- Either fix the installer problem and complete the upgrade
- Find a way to transfer my data to the external HD first, than erase my Macintoch HD and try again the upgrade.

Please if you have anyclue, I'm really stuck here, and I can't afford to lose either my internal or external hard drives data.

Thanks in advance

P.S:
I have tried the solutions over here http://reviews.cnet.com/8301-13727_7-57608837-263/how-to-manage-a-failed-os-x-mavericks-installation/ but I couldn't solve my problem yet

Comment: Why did you post this on stack overflow?

Comment: I didn't know where else I should post it

Comment: http://apple.stackexchange.com

Comment: thanks, I'll keep it in minde

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have a damaged file system and it cannot be repaired. to find out why reboot while holding down command+R and in recovery mode open disk utility and try to repair the disk. It will tell you why it cannot be repaired.

It may be that you need to replace the disk or just reformat it. you will need to format it as HFS+ for you to be able to install on it. ***you will lose all data on the disk! back up your data before reformatting***

report back here after figuring out why the disk cannot be repaired and i will update my answer.

Comment: I couldn't figure out why the disk cannot be repaired, and I've ended up reformatting the disk (which costs me a lot of work to do later :( )